# Laravel : How to pass variable from View (javascript) to Controller?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm extremely new to Laravel (level -0). Our backend guy used it for a web app that we are developing. So after googling i finally figured out how to pass variables from Controller to View. Now i need to pass from View to Controller. I saw that there are some question regarding this but the way its been asked/answered i really dont understand. So what i have now is

Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $title = "Congratulations";
    $messageOne = "You've learned something new!";
    $messageTwo = "Remember all the tips!";
    return view('pages.index',compact('title','messageOne'));
}
```

View (where i want the string to be displayed) :

```
<div>
    {{$title}}
    <br>
    {{$messageOne}}
</div>
```

These messages (messageOne, and others) will change depending on button click which is controlled via js. I was thinking in the js function i could have a variable set like :

```
$('thebutton').click(function(){
    var buttonclicked = "learning"; 
})
```

then send that variable to Controller then in Controller (im not sure how to code it but..) check what the string of buttonclicked variable is and depending on the string return to View the message string. From searches i have to also tweak the Route (which im not sure about as well)?

is that flow possible? otherwise, advice on how i can do this will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
the suggested link to another question in the comment helped which answers the question. also, all the answers helped in some way so im not sure which to choose. Do i have to choose only 1?

Comment: You can use AJAX to send values from the client side to the server. As you're already using jQuery, try [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: Isent it alot simpler to just change the text with javascript, once the button is clicked? Why do you need to send it to your controller?

Answer (score 0):

View to Controller. You can post data via ajax call.
or Submit the form data to controller form post method

```
<form method="post" action="/controller" />

<input type="text" value="100" id="txt" name="txt" />

<button type="submit"/>

</form>
```

Once submit data 100 go to controller. By this way we can pass data to controller.

**JS to Controller Pass data**

```
var pincode = $('#pincode').val();
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:"{{ route('post_data') }}",
           data:{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}","postal":pincode},
           success:function(data){
              //Success code
           }
        });
```

Controller code like below

```
public function post_data(Request $request)
    {
        $postal_code = addslashes($request->all()['postal']);
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

One way you can send it using the `$.ajax()` or the other way you can send it using query parameters like so:

```
<a href={{ route('route-name', ['param 1' => 'Param 1 Value', ......]) }}Click me!</a>
```

Then in your route define your route as following.

```
Route::get('/url/{param1}/{param2}/.....', 'ControllerName@MethodName')->name('route-name');
```

Then go to your controller and define your function like so:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function functionName(Request $request){
    // Get your variables from $request
    $param1 = $request->param1;
    $param2 = $request->param2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS you should use ajax for passing data from view to controller for example

```
$('thebutton').click(function(){
    var buttonclicked = "learning"; 

    //her xyz your url 
    $.get( "xyz", { value: buttonclicked  } )
     .done(function( data ) {
      //write your code after success
    });
});
```

then in controller get the value from ajax request

```
public function test(Request $request){
  dd($request->value);
}
```